# is playframework truly asynchronous?

Tags: playframework

Best answer is in the comments section(so I can't give them points for the answer :( ).

I was wondering if playframework was asynchronous in this fashion(which would be truly asynchronous, or fully asynchronous).  Yes, play is asynchronous on the front end allowing 1000 clients on 100 threads, but on the backend, there is no way to achieve this, or am I wrong(which I hope to be).....

```
public static void someRequest(String id) {

     //This method adds listener to a nio socket listener so it returns
     //IMMEDIATELY and page can't be rendered at this point
     fetchRemoteDataFromOtherSystem(id, new MyListener());

     // DO NOT RENDER PAGE YET but return so thread can be used for other requests
}

public class MyListener extends SomeListener {
    public void fireResponse(Response response) {
        renderPage(response);
    }
}
```

NOTICE that this would be extreme asynchronous behavior and also note that if you have a backend system that takes seconds to respond to each request, you now need about 100 less machines to serve the same amount of users.  In normal contexts where backend system is very fast, there would be no performance difference of course.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Have you read this http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous ? Especially the stuff about Promises. This may also be of interest: http://caffeinelab.net/2010/06/29/asynchronous-http-client-in-play-framework/

Comment: okay, that was awesome, post it as the answer....that second link is extremely clear!!!! great answer!!!!(how come I can't mark comments as the correct answer :( ).

Comment: hmmm, that example shows a Future which has no ability to add a listener so then play must be doing a poll on the Future and asking isDone, isDone over and over????  That kind of stinks....why not just use the response thread to notify play which then would call down into the controller method the second time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [Play 2.0](https://github.com/playframework/Play20). It's still a beta version, but it has [some nice asynchronous stuff](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaAsync).

For the first Play, take a look at [this documentation page](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous), which covers Play's asynchronous features, and the [Play Akka module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/akka) (and while you're at it, also [Akka itself](http://akka.io/) :) ).

Comment: QUESTION: It says it suspends the operation....what does that mean?  If I am making an nio request, I can return a Promise right away and send it to the await method...is it doing some bytecode magic to then return up the call stack and when I invoke the promise object with a response, it then continues?  I could see that and if so, pretty damn sweet that you can write synchronous code and it becomes asynchronous.

Comment: We went to play 2.0 and it was ALOT slower development productivity-wise than play 1.2.x.  We eventually reverted all our 2.0 scala code back to 1.2.x java code.  (We do like scala but even tweaks to an html paged caused a whole recompile that was really annoying).

Comment: If you make the same request in different tabs in the same browser, they seem to be synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

play 2 is totaly asynchronous from ground up and it uses akka and netty. You can use play for both Your front end and services (eg: as rest). Also play is stateless, so, it's very easy to scale it up by adding servers.

Comment: more detail would be great on this though.....is it like the above.  Is there a doc on it?

Comment: here is a video from scala days explaining async behavior http://days2011.scala-lang.org/node/138/296  Also this document is a good resource https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaHome

Answer (score 0):

Adding some detail here.  It does look like Play invented something called a Promise object that extends Future and has a way to add a listener so I assume play adds a listener on the Promise object right after you sent your request and when your response thread calls Promise.setResponse(xxx), that method will check if listener has been added yet and if so will invoke the listener to tell play that response is received and play will then dump it in it's queue to be processed on it's threads.

IF however your response beats play frameworks adding it's listener, when play calls addListener, I am "assuming" it has code to that checks was response already set on object and if so, call the listener using playframeworks existing thread which drops it in the playframework's queue(or at least I hope that is the case).

I do not know if Promise was ported back to play 1.2.x however as the example was using a Future which play would have to do polling on to see when the response comes back...ick....I always wondered why there was no addResponseListener on these Future objects...never liked that.